# Searching through concated arrays using filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter

I have created some arrays and want to search for some string data in them. So i figured out that i may concate all the arrays in one and should search through it for the data i need to search. But the issue is when i try to search through the final array it gives me error. posting the code below.

```
const filters = {
    listName: '',
    name: '',
    number: '',
    designation: ''
};

let mpc = getSavedArray('mpcData');
let mpe = getSavedArray('mpeData');
let div = getSavedArray('divData');
let dist = getSavedArray('distData');
let teh = getSavedArray('tehData');

const allArrays = function () {
    return (mpe.concat(mpc, dist, div, teh));
};
console.log(allArrays());

const searchData = function (arrays, filters) {
    const filteredArray = arrays.filter(function (query) {
        return query.name.toLowerCase().includes(filters.name.toLowerCase())
    })
    document.querySelector('#search-results').innerHTML = ''
    filteredArray.forEach(function (query) {
        const allResult = generateDomElement(query)
        document.querySelector('#search-results').appendChild(allResult)
    })
};

searchData(allArrays, filters);

document.querySelector('#search-record').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    filters.name = e.target.value
    searchData(allArrays, filters);
})
```

Comment: it comes with the error that "TypeError: arrays.filter is not a function"

Comment: That's because it isn't. You're passing in `allArrays`, which is a **function**, not an array.

Comment: The first parameter to `searchData` is supposed to be an array but you sometime pass a function (`allArrays`) as the first parameter. You probably want to pass the result of calling this function (eg: `searchData(allArrays(), filters)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the function `allArrays` itself to `searchData`. You should invoke it.

```
searchData(allArrays, filters);
```

Should be

```
searchData(allArrays(), filters);
```